# onError for SVG Image Tag

Tags: image, svg

With normal HTML images, there is the onError attribute which fires if the image cannot be displayed or the link is broken, does anyone know if there is an equivalent (or work around which achieves the same) for the Image tag in SVG?

I'm happy to use javascript if there is no native option.

Along the lines of:

```
<svg>
  <image xlink:href="path/to/image.jpg" onError="path/to/alternate.png" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi Robert, do you have a documentation link?

Comment: [This works for me on Firefox](https://bug500261.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=385088) YMMV with other UAs

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70259346/fallback-if-image-not-found