# Fallback if image not found

Tags: image, svg

If the file specified on an SVG `<image>` element is not found then the results are unpredictable. In Firefox, I get no indication and no error. In Chrome, I get some default box-shaped scenery image.

Is there a way to provide an alternative image, such as a nice error marker? I have seen solutions for a similar issue in HTML that involve the attribute:

```
onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='Default.jpg'"
```

But this does not work in my SVG (even after changing `src` to `href`). I have also seen a cheat where using an additional `src` attribute provides a fallback for normal the `href` (see [SVG Fallbacks](https://css-tricks.com/svg-fallbacks/)) but it seemed to rely on a quirk of the implementation within the browser and no longer works (at least not in Firefox).

I'm looking for a method that works at least in Firefox, Chrome, and Edge.

Comment: Many thanks, as usual Robert. This even works in IE11. Do you want to make it into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
this.href.baseVal='Default.jpg'
```

Due to SVG's support for SMIL

Comment: The only slight downside of this approach is that I need to add the onerror to every single image element (I have a lot). I cannot find a way of adding these dynamically because the load event is too late for the error detection.